# ToListAsync() in a DbContext using statement : "The ObjectContext disposed", How to deal?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to get a linq query result using `.ToListAsync()` Inside a using statement of the DbContext, code :

```
private async Task<List<String>> GetEntiteesAsync()
{
     Task<List<String>> returnValue;

     using (var entities = new REPORTEntities())
     {
          returnValue = (from user in entities.USERs
                         group user by user.entite into g
                               select g.Key).ToListAsync();
     }

     return await returnValue;
}
```

when running I get the "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection." as shown :

[image]

I suppose that this is caused by the fact that the Context was disposed while the returnValue object was still receiving the objects asynchronously as a List, Is there a workaround to avoid this error while keeping the using statement, or I should just go by doing :

```
private async Task<List<String>> GetEntiteesAsync()
{
     Task<List<String>> returnValue;

     var entities = new REPORTEntities()

     returnValue = (from user in entities.USERs
                    group user by user.entite into g
                    select g.Key).ToListAsync();

     return await returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're leaving the `using` scope before the `ToListAsync` operation completes because you're not awaiting the asynchronous task, which means `entities` is disposed too soon (hence the object disposed exception).

You should just return the result while inside the scope and the `async-await` mechanism will make sure `Dispose` is called after the operation completes asynchronously:

```
private async Task<List<String>> GetEntiteesAsync()
{
     using (var entities = new REPORTEntities())
     {
          return await (from user in entities.USERs
                         group user by user.entite into g
                               select g.Key).ToListAsync();
     }
}
```

Comment: Aw, I got blinded ! should have done that like that since the beginning, don't know whay I complicated it , Thx sir !

Comment: @AymenDaoudi Sure, any time.